# invalid source in php dynamic/generated audio player

Tags: php, dynamic, html5-audio

Web browsers are determining that my php generated audio players have invalid sources.  I am also getting a sort an injection of '   0' right before my pagination links.

I honestly don't understand.  I've also inspected the elemnts in several web browsers and they all look are showing me valid html code.

```
<?php 
    include_once("connect.php");
    $count_query =  mysqli_query($dbhandle,"SELECT NULL FROM my_audio");
    $count = mysqlI_num_rows($count_query);

    $previous_page = "'                  'Previous";
    $next_page = "Next ";
    //global $output;
    //pagination starts here
    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$_GET['page']);
    }
    else
    {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $perPage = 5;
    $lastPage = ceil($count/$perPage);

    if($page <1)
    {
        $page =1;
    }
    else if($page>$lastPage)
    {
        $page = $lastPage;
    }

    $limit = "LIMIT ".($page - 1)*$perPage.",$perPage";
    //$limit = " LIMIT 0,1";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbhandle,"SELECT * FROM my_audio $limit");
    if($lastPage != 1)
    {
        $output = '';
        $pagination=0;
        if($page != $lastPage)
        {
            $next = $page + 1;
            $pagination.='<a href="sqltest1.php?page='.$next.'">'.$next_page.'</a>';
        }

        if($page != 1)
        {
            $prev = $page - 1;
            $pagination.='<a href="sqltest1.php?page='.$prev.'">'.$previous_page.'</a>';
        }

    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $sourcefile=$row['location'];
        **$output.='<audio controls="controls"><source src="'.$sourcefile.'" type="audio/mpeg"> Your browser does not support the audio tag.</audio><br><br>';
    }** 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="Blueprint: Slide and Push Menus" />
        <title> Some Practice Stuff</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Php Pagination Trial</h1>
        <?php echo $output;?>
        <?php echo $pagination;?>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you 'The Blue Dog' for that bit of advice, it worked perfectly.  The other issue that I have is still persistent; the sources to the audio players are declared as invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising `$pagination` as a numeric variable with a value of zero instead of as an empty string. This means when you concatenate it with a string it will be prefixed with a `0`.

Change:

```
$pagination=0;
```

to:

```
$pagination="";
```